What is causing my coroutine not to start?
I'm trying to spawn a circle to show the splash radius of a projectile but the coroutine to destroy the object is not running.
The prefab is spawning in like I expect it to but it is not destroyed.
Currently the script reads,
public GameObject splashObjPrefab;


if (splash)
{
    GameObject _splashObj = Instantiate(splashObjPrefab, this.transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
    _splashObj.transform.localScale = new Vector3(splashRange * 2, splashRange * 2, 1);

    StartCoroutine(DestroySplash(_splashObj));

    Debug.Log("Run Coroutine");
}

    Destroy(gameObject);

}

private IEnumerator DestroySplash(GameObject _splashObj)
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.2f);

    Debug.Log("DestroySplash");
    Destroy(_splashObj);
}

The console is showing the 'Run couroutine' text but not the 'DestroySplash' Text

Coroutines start the next frame. Destroy(gameObject); runs in the current frame and without a game object there is nothing to run the coroutine.

Oh, that make sense, I'm still struggling to get it to work, I tried setting gameObject to inactive which did not work and I tried destroying the gameObject in the coroutine which also did not destroy the splashObj either.

Inactive objects also do not run coroutines. Why not have the splash object run the coroutine and destroy itself?
